# Java strange assignment issue

Tags: java, eclipse, variable-assignment

I have got a problem and can't get my head around it.

I assigned integer `a` to member `dataAction` in method `setDataAction(int a)` of class `Action`.

After assignment the values are still different! `a == -3`, `dataAction == 0`. No error or complaint was evoked neither by Eclipse nor by Java.

**Environment:** Win7-64 with Eclipse Juno and JDK-7u25-win-64.

To prevent any comment in this direction, the assignment was done on an instance of the class. I have tried it on several machines and even set up a pristine one with definitely no virus, only OS & Environment!

a better picture of the debugger screen shot is available as well at:
http://setosix.eu/Java_Assignment_Problem.jpg / .gif / .png

```
    // Class to hold return values of the applet to determine further action
    class Action implements Constants {
      int dataAction;
      int appletAction;
      int dataResult;

      Action() {
        dataAction = MOVE_NOT;
        appletAction = ACT_CONTINUE;
        dataResult = LV_OK;
      }

      public void setDataAction(int a) {
        dataAction = a;
      }
    }

    // here the 'Action' instance is created
    public class TableResource extends Database {
      private Connection dbLink;
      private Statement stmt;
      protected ResultSet rs;
      // hold the return values of applet 
      protected Action nextAction;

      protected TableResource() {
        dbLink = getInstance().getConnection();
        rs = null;
        stmt = null;
        nextAction = new Action();
      }
      ...

     // data class for 'AppletMandanten' 
     public class DataMandanten extends TableResource implements Data {
     ...

    // constants are defined here
    public interface Constants  {
      // constants defining moves in record-/browse-mode 
      public static final int MOVE_NOT = 0;
      public static final int MOVE_FIRST = -1;
      public static final int MOVE_LAST = -2;
      public static final int MOVE_NEXT = -3;
      public static final int MOVE_PREVIOUS = -4;
      public static final int MOVE_NEXTPAGE = -5;
      public static final int MOVE_PREVPAGE = -6;
      ...


    // interface ‘Data’ extends interface ‘Constants’
    public interface Data extends Constants {
    ... 


    // in this class the instance ‘data’ is creates
    public class ModulMandanten extends EventHandler implements Data {
    ...

      // main control of applet
      public int control() {
        int leave = LV_OK;
        DataMandanten data;

        // connect to database
        db = Database.getInstance();

        if( db.dbConnect() < 0 ) {
          Intelligence.out( 1,  "ERROR in ("+"RWG"+"): Failed to connect to Server!");
          leave = LV_ERROR;
        }   

        // here ‘data’ instance is created 
        data = new DataMandanten();
        ...


    public abstract class Applet extends ModulMandanten {
    ...

    // here the invocation takes place
    public class AppletMandanten extends Applet {
    ... 

      // handle events in class ‘AppleMandanten’ (derives from ‘ActionPerformed()’
      private void eventHandler( ActionEvent event ) {
      ...
        // invocation is called in method 'eventHandler', class 'AppletMandanten'
        switch (eventName){     
          case ("btnNext"): {
            // 'next' button pressed
            data.nextAction.setDataAction( MOVE_NEXT );
            // alternatively: doesn't work neither 
            data.nextAction.setDataAction = MOVE_NEXT;
            // 'data.nextAction.setDataAction' printed to console ( != MOVE_NEXT ) 
            System.out.println(Integer.toString(data.nextAction.dataAction));
            break;
           // !!! after this 'dataAction' isn't touched again !!!
         }
         ...
```

[Java assignment issue in Eclipse debug mode http://setosix.eu/Java_Assignment_Problem.jpg](http://setosix.eu/Java_Assignment_Problem.jpg)

Comment: Show us how you called `setDataAction`. Are you calling it on the same instance?

Comment: Also show us how you tested that `dataAction` was unchanged.

Comment: Can we see the creation of the object and the invocation of the setDataAction() method?  Could it be that you're not invoking the method on the instance you think you are?

I compiled your class, and called:
`public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                Action a = new Action();
                a.setDataAction(12);
                System.out.println(a.dataAction);
        }
}
`
Output:
java Test
12

Comment: primitive int instance variables are initialized to 0 on instance creation, so if you've tried to assign something else to it and still 0, your assignment (or most likely - the code before assignment) must have failed and threw an exception, so the assignment to to -3 never took place.

Comment: To test that 'dataAction' was unchanged, I tested it as stated above by the debugger and with 'System.out.prinln( Integer.toString(dataAction));' in the method 'setDataAction(int a)' beneath the assignment statement.

Comment: just give us your full invocation code...

Comment: I called the same and only instance of this class. I verified it by checking the id of the object via 'object.toString()'.

Comment: no exception is thrown whatsoever. The program is quite complex so I just can give you the creation of the instance which is 'Action nextAction = new Action()' and the invocation is 'object.nextAction.setDataAction( -3)' where 'object' is an instance of the mother class (not parent!) of which 'nextAction' is a 'protcted' member.

Comment: Addendum: in the class of invocation of setDataAction(-3)' I checked  immediately if the value was assigned and strangly it was, but as soon as I return to the class where 'nextAction' is a member of the value changes back to '0'. I checked it step by step with the debugger, I checked if any other assignmnets took place, I checked all over the whole code if any assignments are made anywhere, I checked by loads of 'System.out.println()`' statements, I checked by making the class public in its own file, I already check for hours and days.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, the whole code is quite complex but no exceptions are thrown or warnings are issued and there are no suppressions of warnings whatsoever in the code.

Comment: As a wild guess, a value that seems to change back immediately sounds like that you actually do not change the variable you think, but a local one.

Comment: One adjustment: what I called 'mother class' is of course the 'parent class'

Comment: I'd be happy if you were right, but unfortunately it is really as strange as iI told and shouldn't happen at all. I tested every thing ten-fold and more. And as I said when watching the debugger when it enters it shows 'a ==-3' and after the assignment 'dataActive = a' it still shows 'a==-3' and 'dataActive==0'. I really liked to post the debugger screen shot if I could, but its availabel at http://setosix.eu/Java_Assignment_Problem.gif

Comment: One last issue: I am not messing around with C or Assembler or anything else, it is pure Java code and not even some exotic methods or libaries, only basic libraries in conjunction with JDBC for MySql

Comment: Are you debugging locally, or remotely.  If you changed the code locally, but are debugging remotely, that can explain weird scenarios like this as the code does not match up.  Also, post the calling code, you don't have enough info here for anyone to really help.

Comment: Is -3 equal to a constant value of some kind, or a truly magic number?

Comment: all happens locally on one machine. the -3 derives from a constant defined as 'public static final int MOVE_NEXT = -3;' but the problem is resistant with each int value.

Comment: The questions doesn't mention threads at all - but I notice from the screenshot that there are several in play. If the write and read are being performed from different threads then this is a simple concurrency issue - making the variable volatile or synchronizing would fix it.

Comment: thanks 'henry' i guess you brought me on a good track. more about it later

Answer (score 1):

Back to basics. Java does assignments right - one cannot expect a bug in this part of Java. When you write `x=a` and a is -3, than x will be -3 immediately afterwards. Several things I see in your code that can go wrong:

**Multiple Threads**

Change your code using `AtomicInteger` and change the caller, so that setting and getting while expecting the same value, is one atomic call to a method of `AtomicInteger`, not separate method calls. `synchronized` would not work in the case of the screenshot above.

**Track back the problem**

Log `a` and `dataAction` before the assignement. And if you want to be sure, directly after the assignment again, but be aware, that another thread could have been jumped in middle and did also a `setDataAction()`. I excpect, that you will find either some strange assigments of 0 or no call with -3.

Now that you see the wrong assignment, add a little code to your `setDataAction()`.

```
// add in setDataAction()
if(a == the-wrong-value) try {
    throw new Exception("wrong assignment: " + a);
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So, you find out, where the wrong assignment comes from and be able to track down what really happens.